# can a user purchase from an iOS app by their prepaid credit?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We want to develop a purchase system for countries that have no access to bank cards like master and visa. so we want to make a user management system, which its users can charge their account by their country bank cards, on a website, and login into the iOS app and purchase a magazine issue(for example) by their credit.
I wonder if it's possible and will it be rejected by apple? because we can't use in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the magazine is an electronic one you have to use In-App-Purchase. If the magazine is made out of paper you are okay with using whatever payment you want. But content that is used inside of the app has to be handled by in-app-purchases.

See [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

> 11.2
>   Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected

However, you can implement this without In-App-Purchase in a way that apple wouldn't reject it. Amazons Kindle app does this for example.
But you need kind of smart users because you are not allowed to tell them that they can pay on your website.

> 11.14
>   Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines, newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is subscribed to or purchased outside of the app

Comment: thank you! we can't use in-app purchase for countries like Iran, so the second way you mentioned will be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. This is coming right out of `Apple Store Review Guidelines`

```
Section 11

11.2    Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected
```